# como crear un mapa

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, mapa

tengo una base de datos con un campo latitud y longitud y necesito crear un mapa y que muestre esa ubicación con esos dos datos, la verdad no se como hacerlo si alguien me puede ayudar muchas gracias.
este es el formulario.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal formvalida" role="form" method="post" id="frm<?php echo $script; ?>" action="<?php echo SIMUtil::lastURI() ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group first ">

                            <div class="form-group first ">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="Latitud">Latitud</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Latitud" name="Latitud" placeholder="" class="form-control" title="Latitud" value="<?php echo $frm["Latitud"] ?>" required></div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="Casa">Longitud</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8"> <input type="text" id="Longitud" name="Longitud" placeholder="" class="form-control" title="Longitud" value="<?php echo $frm["Longitud"] ?>" required></div>


                                </div>

                            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Al preguntar deberías realizar por partes, ya que estas preguntando por una solución de varias partes. ¿Cual es el problema que tienes en el código mostrado o simplemente deseas opiniones?, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para la creación de un mapa debes usar JavaScript mas concretamente la librería LeafLet, con esta librería podrás manipular los mapas a como quieras dentro de la capa que decidas mostrarlo.

Primero incluye en tu header el css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
```

luego al final de tu body incluye el js

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

Después tienes este código de ejemplo donde se muestran los métodos principales básicos para que te funcione el mapa en este caso dentro de

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

En la capa anterior se mostraría el mapa evidentemente esa capa debe tener su propio estilo como width y height para que el mapa se visualice correctamente

```
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('El mensaje que quieras mostrar en el PopUp.')
    .openPopup();
</script>
```